# Reachability issue with iOS8

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, reachability

I am facing issue in iOS8.0. 
Before a UPNP search I am checking for wifi connection using Apple's Reachability code.

All things runs fine on iOS7 and earlier versions but for iOS8.0 beta5  (iPad mini, iPad air) it is failing and giving wrong results(i.e WIFI not reachable etc..) even when wifi is available.

Is Someone else is facing the same issue. and found a solution for this.
Do let me know. Also do let me know if this is an Apple issue as this issue doesnt appears on all devices.

Comment: Same problem here on iOS8 on an iPhone 6. Trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Krumelur as per i got it seems like Reachability is taking too much time to respond on some devices.. Seems like not only Tim has spoiled iPhone reputation with #bendgate but also spoiled the iOS8 as well..

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

I also get same problem in one of my application, in this app i was using old Reachability with version 2.2, I replace this reachability files with apples latest version 3.5, and it works.

Please check the version of your Reachability file,

You can get latest version of Reachability from below path:

[Apple Reachability 3.5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope it helps You.!