# Why does the Reachability class return unexpected results for iOS8?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, reachability

When my application initially starts up, I am calling [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]. I am essentially calling this right after -application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: in the AppDelegate. In iOS8, this is returning a valid connection when I am in airplane mode or have turned off wi-fi. In iOS7, the Reachability class is returning expected results (not connected). Could the issue be related to when I am calling the method?

I was able to work around this issue by implementing Ad-J’s answer here: [Easiest way to detect Internet connection on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812459/easiest-way-to-detect-internet-connection-on-ios) when detecting that the device is on iOS8.

Has anyone else seen this issue?

Comment: You are not alone. Even i am facing issues with Reachability code on iOS 8.0. here i arleady raised a question but nobody answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719500/reachability-issue-with-ios8 Seems like Tim Cook of apple has messed up the Reachability in iOS8.0.

Comment: @Dinesh, Tim Cook is the last person who can mess up even a bit in the Apple's APIs...

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I also get same problem in one of my application, in this app i was using old Reachability with version 2.2, I replace this reachability files with apples latest version 3.5, and it works.

Please check the version of your Reachability file,

You can get latest version of Reachability from below path:

[Apple Reachability 3.5](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope it helps You.!

Comment: Already tried that thing. but even this doesn't works in my case.